# How to add the Graphics3D import to my Java program?

Tags: java

I need to work on a couple of examples in Graphics in Java 3D but I never can find the add on or class that I have to import into Java for the Graphics3D portion of the programming

**Question: How can this Graphics3D class be downloaded and installed on Eclipse and NetBeans IDE to work with examples and to allow programming?**

Code:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics gfx) {
    super.paintComponent(gfx);
    if (DEBUG) {
        System.out.println("paintComponent(): isPainting " + isPainting);
        System.out.println("paintCounter " + paintCounter);
    }
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) gfx;  <-- This works fine but how is the 3D imported
    Graphics3d g  = new Graphics3d (g2); <-- Cannot find this class
```

How can I install the Graphics3D into my program with an import. I have been looking to add this functionality to my Eclipse for sometime but have not been able to get it to work.

I have not download the Graphics3D files that I am aware of. I have tried to do this on many occasions but I do not think any of them have been successfully installed. Can this be done from Java's web site?

If I was going to start at the beginning like nothing had been done what would be the steps to down load the Graphic3D and install and then be able to use in my code.

Comment: This could be one of many issues, you should supply more details of what Graphics3d is, what you have tried out so far and so on. I'll start with one question. Have you downloaded the dependency (source files, class files, jar file?) that contains this Graphics3d class yet?

Comment: What example are you trying to compile? `Graphics3D` is not a class from the standard library, so you will need to get this from somewhere else.

Comment: That is what I am certain of were do I get the Graphics3D class from or would it be better to use something like OpenGL or someother third part graphics software.

Comment: Any class that I can find on the internet, was just looking to compile some examples and see what happens.